# Implicit generic type conversion fails to match overloaded method signature

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

I have some classes as follows:

```
public class RowBase { }

public class SpecificRow : RowBase { }

public class RowListItem<TRow> where TRow : RowBase { }

public class SpecificRowListItem : RowListItem<SpecificRow> { }
```

And some methods as follows:

```
public string GetName<TRow>(RowBase row) where TRow : RowBase { }

public string GetName<TRow>(RowListItem<TRow> item) where TRow : RowBase { }
```

The problem I'm having is that a subclass of `RowListItem` fails to match the signature of the second overload.  Here are examples:

```
var foo = new SpecificRow();
var bar = new SpecificRowListItem();
var baz = new RowListItem<SpecificRow>();
string name;
name = GetName(foo); // invokes first overload as expected
name = GetName(baz); // invokes second overload as expected
name = GetName(bar); // does not compile
name = GetName((RowListItem<SpecificRow>)bar); // this alternative invokes the second overload
name = GetName<SpecificRow>(bar); // this alternative also invokes the second overload
```

The compiler error is

> Error CS0311  The type 'ConsoleApplication1.SpecificRowListItem' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRow' in the generic type or method 'Program.GetName(TRow)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ConsoleApplication1.SpecificRowListItem' to 'ConsoleApplication1.RowBase'.

Since `SpecificRowListItem` is a subclass of `RowListItem<TRow>` with a `TRow` that meets the `where TRow : RowBase` constraint, I would expect that the compiler would be able to tell that it should match the second overload when provided a parameter as an instance of that class.  However, the text of the compiler error indicates that it's attempting to match the first overload (`GetName(TRow)`).  I'd like to understand why that is, and if there's anything I can do to solve the problem other than the two alternatives that are working.  I tried this:

```
public string GetName<TItem, TRow>(TItem item)
    where TItem : RowListItem<TRow>
    where TRow : RowBase
```

Aside from being ugly, it gave me the same problem (appears to match the first overload).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RowListItem<SpecificRow>` has no relation to `RowListItem<BaseRow>`, it does not derive from it.

check out co-variance in generics. this answer might help you: ["out T" vs. "T" in Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956993/out-t-vs-t-in-generics)

Working example:

```
  using System;

namespace CoVariance
{
    public class RowBase { }

    public class SpecificRow : RowBase { }

    public class RowListItem<TRow> : IInputSave<TRow> where TRow : RowBase { }

    public class SpecificRowListItem : RowListItem<SpecificRow> { }

    internal interface IInputSave<out TRow>
        where TRow : RowBase
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args){

            var foo = new SpecificRow();
            var bar = new SpecificRowListItem();
            var baz = new RowListItem<SpecificRow>();
            string name;

            name = GetName(foo);
            Console.WriteLine(name); //oink
            name = GetName(baz);
            Console.WriteLine(name); //nested oink
            name = GetName(bar);
            Console.WriteLine(name); //nested oink
            name = GetName((RowListItem<SpecificRow>)bar);
            Console.WriteLine(name); //nested oink
            //name = GetName<SpecificRow>(bar); 

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string GetName(RowBase row)
        {
            return "oink";
        }

        public static string GetName(IInputSave<RowBase> item)
        {
            return "nested oink";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not following you.  Based on how I understand your answer, `GetName((RowListItem<SpecificRow>)bar)` should also fail, since it doesn't derive from `RowListItem<BaseRow>`.  However, it succeeds because of the `where TRow : BaseRow` constraint, which matches any `TRow` that inherits from `BaseRow`.  My question is whether there's a reason the compiler can't implicitly cast from `SpecificRowListItem` to `RowListItem<SpecificRow>` even though the first inherits from the second?

Comment: i added a working example to my answer based on your example for leveraging co-variance in c#.
but i am not able to properly explain it to you, since i dont fully understand it myself xD
but there is a lot to read about that stuff on the internet :d

Comment: I'm glad you don't understand it either--makes me feel like less of a doofus ;-)  [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9381751/4062628) was interesting as well.